# Process not terminated when exception occured in thread c#

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, process, terminate

I have a System.Timers.Timer and I found out that in the ElapsedEventHandler an exception sometimes occured but the process did *not* die but the thread executing the ElapsedEventHandler died quitly where exception occured. Not good since I then wasn't aware about the exception. Why isn't the process terminated? How could I get the process terminated in best way in case an exception occurs in the ElapsedEventHandler?

I tried similar using a System.Threading.Timer and then the process terminated.
Can you explain the difference?

Complete code below:

```
class Program
{
    static public void DoBad()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoBad enter");
        string s = "hello";
        object o = s;
        int i = (int)o; // Ops! Something unexpected happend here... Exception
        Console.WriteLine("DoBad exit");
    }

    static void DoIt1(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDoIt1 enter");
        DoBad(); // Process is NOT terminated when excpetion occurs in DoBad, thread just dies quietly but process continues. Why is process not terminated?
        Console.WriteLine("DoIt1 exit");
    }

    static void Test1()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DoIt1);
        t.Enabled = true;
    }

    static public void DoIt2(Object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDoIt2 enter");
        DoBad(); // Process terminated when exception occurs in DoBad.
        Console.WriteLine("DoIt2 exit");
    }

    static void Test2()           
    {
        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoIt2, null, 0, 2000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test1(); // Process NOT terminated when exception occurs in DoBad
        // Test2(); // Process terminated when exception occurs in DoBad

        // Why is process NOT terminated when running Test1 (but terminated when running Test2)?
        // Want process to die. How to do it in best way?

        Console.WriteLine("Main Sleep");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(11000);
        Console.WriteLine("Main Slept");
    }
}
```

/ Thanks!

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is just plain nasty that way.  It swallows all exceptions thrown by the Elapsed event handler.  Either catch them yourself or favor System.Threading.Timer

Answer (score 0):

this is done by design, as you can see here: ([system.timers.timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx))
In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and earlier, the Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework.

the system.threading.timer doesn't do this, so the exception is passed out and terminates the process.
if you would like to know about the exception, then you should catch it and log it.
if you want all the work to be done in the main thread, you can either use invoke/begininvoke:

```
form1.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate
                {
                //do something
                });
```

or use the Windows.forms.timer (winforms) / System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer (WPF)